# What is << and <<= different in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am a newbie about Ruby on Rails. I know << operator what it is doing but I am working with datatable and I have codes like these:

```
def data
    items.map do |donation|
      [].tap do |column|
        column << donation_path(donation)
        column <<= current_user.admin? ? link_to(donation.sender.name, admin_store_path(donation.sender)) : donation.sender.name 
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried to <<= in rails c and the result is:

```
irb(main):001:0> ar = []
=> []
irb(main):002:0> ar << 1
=> [1]
irb(main):003:0> ar <<= 1
=> [1, 1]
irb(main):004:0> ar <<= 2
=> [1, 1, 2]
```

I think <<= is similar with << but I have to be sure.

Comment: Please remove the rails tag. There is nothing in your question, which would be specific to Rails.

Comment: I removed the rails tag 

Comment: Similar in its result, but not identical: `ar << 1 << 2` works as expected (it pushes both values to the array) whereas `a <<= 1 <<= 2` gives a syntax error and `a <<= 1 << 2` returns `[4]` due to [`Integer#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Integer.html#3C-3C-method) and operator precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an operator *op=* in Ruby, the expression

x *op=* y

is equivalent to

x = x *op* y

In your case, it means that an

```
a <<= b
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a << b
```

but since `a << b` already modifies `a`, you gain nothing from using `<<=`.

NOTE: As was pointed out in the comments, this does not apply for the operator `[]`: If you want to have an assignment version, you have to define `[]=` explicitly.

Comment: _"and the class does not provide a definition for this operator"_ – abbreviated assignment is handled by the parser. You cannot implement `<<=` (or any other `op=` as a method. The only exception is `[]=` (and here, implementing `[]` doesn't give you `[]=`)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was not aware of this, and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: hey, I figured it out. I used <<= cz always condition was returning true when I was using <<